# image disapper after opening it in a jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog

i have a code that opens the image in a dialog when clicked and it works fine but the problem is that the image clicked disappear from its position after it opens in the dialog, here is the code i am using:

```
        $(function () {
        $("img").click(function (s) {
            $(this).dialog({
                height: 750,
                width: 650,
                modal: true,
                zIndex:900
            });
        });
    });
```

what is the problem , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could open a clone of the image, so the original doesn't disappear:

```
   $(function () {
        $("img").click(function (s) {
            $(this).clone().dialog({
                height: 750,
                width: 650,
                modal: true,
                zIndex:900
            });
        });
    });
```

Hope this helps. Cheers